# ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to load data into a Hive table from Teradata using sqoop.

I am using CDH4.3 version. i am getting the following error..

> ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detected incompatible parameters: Unsupported parameter: --hive-import

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

This is my script

> sqoop import --hive-overwrite --hive-drop-import-delims --warehouse-dir "/warehouse" --hive-table aster_sq \
>   --connect jdbc:teradata://xxxxx/DATABASE=xxxx \
>   --table aster2 --username xxxx --password xxxxx --hive-import\
>    --fields-terminated-by ',' --lines-terminated-by '\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception I would say that you are using "Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata" that sadly do not currently support Hive imports and hence the exception about Unsupported parameter --hive-import. You can easily workaround the issue by using the connector to import data into HDFS as they are and loading them into Hive using "LOAD DATA" command yourself. Another workaround is to use older "Cloudera Connector for Teradata" that do support the hive import. This should be fixed in upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0):

The --hive-import is apparently supported for this command. Did you make sure to install the Teradata jar files?

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/cloudera-connector-for-teradata-1-0-0/